# Could i use right outer join and inner join together?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm trying to get the data from 3 tables but i think i need to use inner join (to join TABLE1 and TABLE2) and right outer join because i need all information from TABLE3 but i don't know how to do it. I tried this:

```
select a.TABLE1_ID, e.TABLE2_ID,f.TABLE3_ID
from TABLE1 as a, TABLE2 as e, TABLE3 as f
where a.TABLE1_ID = e.TABLE2_ID and a.TABLE1_COL = f.TABLE3_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT f.TABLE3_ID, NULL
FROM TABLE3 as f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1 as a
    WHERE a.TABLE1_COL = f.TABLE3_ID);
```

But i get the following error:
*The operands of a set operator or a VALUES clause do not have the same number of columns.. SQLCODE=-421, SQLSTATE=42826, DRIVER=4.19.56*

How could i do it? Is it possible?

**EDIT: 
The following is the result that i would like to get:

```
a.TABLE1_ID | e.TABLE2_ID | f.TABLE3_ID
----------------------------------------
AFR123      | AFR123      | MM145FR123
AFR124      | AFR124      | MM145FR124
NULL        | NULL        | MM145FR125
NULL        | NULL        | MM145FR126
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
select a.TABLE1_ID, e.TABLE2_ID, f.TABLE3_ID
from TABLE3 f left join
     TABLE1 a
     ON a.TABLE1_ID = f.TABLE3_ID left join
     TABLE2 e 
     on a.TABLE1_ID = e.TABLE2_ID ;
```

As a note:  If there is a row in `a` that matches `f` but has no matching row in `e`, then this keeps the values from `a`.  If you using `INNER JOIN` followed by `RIGHT JOIN`, you won't have the values in the intermediate table.  Usually having such values is desired.